# Swift 4 how to count the distance between 2 elements in an array with all unique elements?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift4

I'm trying to create a simple array in my apps. May I know how to calculate distance between 2 elements in my array? Example:-

I have an array as below:-

var aryNumberList = ["7","4","8","6","9","1"]

if i get my textfield A = 7 and textfield B = 9
So my expected output is 4

if i get my textfield A = 6 and textfield B = 1
So my expected output is 2

if i get my textfield A = 1 and textfield B = 6
So my expected output is 4 (** will continue from begin)

Your help is appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var positionA = 0 // declare as global variable
var positionB = 0 // declare as global variable

for i in 0 ..< aryNumberList.count  {

    if Int(aryNumberList[i]) == textfieldA.text {

            positionA = i
    }

    if Int(aryNumberList[i]) == textfieldB.text {

            positionB = i
    }
}

if positionA > positionB {

    print("** will continue from begin")

}else {

    var distance = positionB - positionA

    print("\(distance)")
}
```

Comment: You've made it more wrong by editing. I don't know how you got 2 upvotes and checkmark for this answer.

Comment: converted string to int

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
func calculateDistance(strings: [String], s1: String, s2: String) -> Int {
    if let firstindex = strings.firstIndex(where: {$0 == s1}),
        let secondIndex = strings.firstIndex(where: {$0 == s2}) {
        return ((secondIndex - firstindex) + strings.count) % strings.count
    } else {
        // One or both inputs not part of the array
        return -1
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var arrayNumberList = ["7","4","8","6","9","1"]

print(calculateDistance(strings: arrayNumberList, s1: "6", s2: "1")) // Prints 2
print(calculateDistance(strings: arrayNumberList, s1: "1", s2: "6")) // Prints 4
```

Comment: Hi @Rakesha, I will put this after a button clicked, so how can I call this func in my button click event?

Comment: @henry you could call the method in the button click selector.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually been the `distance(from:to:)` method for `Collection` conforming types since Xcode 10.0

```
extension Collection where Element: Equatable {
    
    func getDistance(from a: Element, to b: Element) -> Int? {
        guard let ixA = firstIndex(of: a),
              let ixB = firstIndex(of: b) else {
            return nil
        }
        return distance(from: ixA, to: ixB)
    }
}

[5,4,3,2,1].getDistance(from: 5, to: 1)
["e","d","c","b","a"].getDistance(from: "a", to: "c")
```